# Speed optimizing a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance

I have a number of JavaScript functions like the following on my page:

```
function fun1(){...}
function fun2(){...}
function fun3(){...}
function fun4(){...}
```

I may use `fun1` in one or two pages, but the other functions only for specific pages.

My question is: should I include all the functions in one file like `script.js` or include specific functions for specific page?  Which one is better for speed optimizing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your question is about optimizing page loading speed.

I would suggest grouping them as mush as possible in a single js file.
Otherwise, you would have to load a lot of small js files, increasing the page loading time.

Consider minifying your JS files too.

Comment: i am using **jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });** for ie issue. is this will  affect the page loading speed

Comment: Parameters can be definied via jQuery.ajax() for per-request params or via jQuery.ajaxSetup() for default params.
If most of your Ajax requests can be cached, you should consider defining "cache: false" only in the non-cachable queries. Otherwise, ajaxSetup() is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the size of the functions, your visitors' access patterns, your cache settings and other circumstances. The speed of downloading a file depends on how many TCP packets the server has to send. (Packet sizes tend to be around 1,5K.) Increasing the file size only matters if means the file needs to be broken into more packets (the client-size delay of processing a script which needs not be run is negligible), so if your scripts are short (you should of course minify them first), its best to alwaays bundle them. If you expect the average visitor to need all scripts eventually, it's again best to send them in one file. If, however, the average visitor won't need some of the larger scripts (for example one part is only needed at upload, and only 0,1% of the visitors ever uploads something), it might be better to send them separately.

Answer (score 0):

The .js files are cached by your browser. So you can include as many functions as you like in a single file. If you split them into separate files that much of additional calls are made from the browser which slows down the loading page.. Also you can compress the js files if you are concerned about the size of the .js file ..@ http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on how your server is sending out these files. If you have Firebug, open up the Net tab and inspect your JS files. If you see a `Last-Modified` entry in the Headers tab, it means that you are better off putting all your JS into one file. If you don't see it, it's best to split things up into page-specific files.

In my opinion, there are four main methods of speeding up your page-load times:

1. server headers -- this one is more complex to set up, but if you control your server settings or if you are willing to serve your JS via a dynamic page (PHP or ASP), you can send extra instructions to the browser to cache specific content for specific periods. Since your JS files are likely to change quite infrequently, it's usually pretty safe to do this for them. You basically just need to set the `Expires` header to some point well into the future. This means that the browser will not need to request the file at all if it has it in the cache. This makes the most sense if you have visitors who come back again and again. If you get a lot of one-hit visitors, this won't make a difference. This does mean that if you change these files, many browsers won't pick up the change; thus you should either change the file name or append something to the query string like this: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/sitescript.js?v=1.1"></script>`. This can be a maintenance problem if you have more than a few static HTML pages.
2. numbers of files -- in my opinion, this is where you get the biggest bang-for-buck savings. I'm nearly certain that most browsers still support only four active requests at a time. That means that if your web page has five images, the last image won't get requested until one of the previous images completes loading. And if your site has 50 images and 3 CSS files and 10 JS files, it's going to take a while to clear all those requests. Remember, even if you are sending `Last-Modified` headers, the browser still needs to check if the content has changed, so it needs one of those request slots. If you can combine all your images into a single images (using CSS sprites) and all your JS into a single file, your pages will load significantly faster.
3. file size -- as the web speeds up, this gets less and less important. If your server does not support content compression, it's a pretty good idea to minify your JS, though the time savings are overrated in my opinion. This does make maintenance somewhat more time-consuming and live debugging nearly impossible, but it definitely brings file size down quite a bit. If you have a LOT of JavaScript (maybe ~150KB+?) or if you know your visitors are coming from slower networks (for example, people on a corporate network), I would recommend doing it. If your server DOES support compression, the savings are actually negligible.
4. script placement -- when the browser hits a `<script src="...">` tag, it halts all rendering until the script has loaded and executed, which means an inevitable delay. If you put your scripts in the middle of your page, you'll note that half the page loads and then pauses. To speek up rendering, place as many of your `<script>` references as you can at the dead bottom of the page. Scripts that you need at the top of the page can go there, but the more `<script>` clutter you have up there, the slower the page will render. Any code that gets executed by `onLoad` or `DOMReady` can safely go at the bottom of the page.

Yahoo has a really quite amazing list of optimization tips at their [Best Practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) page.